# ASP.NET MVC - View is posting null model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been trying to call a POST action from my view. I see POST method parameter is always null. What I am doing wrong ?

My model class :

```
public class Survey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string ResponseText { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

My controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Publish(List<Survey> surveyToSave)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        //Save logc 

        return View("Index");
    }
```

View code:

```
    @model List<Survey>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Publish","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="center-div">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <div id=@item.QuestionId class="Question">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.QuestionText</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                              <div>
                                    <label>
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Find(i => i.QuestionId == item.QuestionId).ResponseText, "Not sure")
                                        Not sure
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <label>
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Find(i => i.QuestionId == item.QuestionId).ResponseText, "Agree")
                                        Agree
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            }

        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit"  value="Publish" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

}
```

Most properties in model is supposed to be populated from view. Idea was to make the model in UI and submit that in post to save.

Comment: will a `public ActionResult Publish([FromBody] List<Survey> surveyToSave)` do the work?

Comment: @FrankNielsen, thanks for checking. I tried that but that did not work as well. Any more suggestions I can try ?

Comment: Can you post the json being send

Comment: @FrankNielsen, I marked the answer and up voted too. Thanks for looking. I was simply missing the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current view code is generating the input element like this, for all the items in the collection.

```
<input id="ResponseText" name="ResponseText" type="radio" value="Not sure" />
```

Model binding will work when the property structure/names matches with the form data posted to your method matches. The default model binder will look into the **name** attribute value of each item in the posted form data and tries to find a matching property in the class object you used as the method parameter and map the values. Since your HttpPost action methods parameter is `List<Survey>`, for model binding to work, your input element names should be some thing like this

```
 <input name="[n].ResponseText" type="radio" value="Not sure" />
```

Where `n` is the index, starting from `0` to `Model.Count-1`

You can convert your view code to use a `for` loop and create input element with above `name` attribute value

```
@model List<Survey>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Publish", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <div class="center-div">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
          <div>
            <label>@Model[i].QuestionText</label>
            <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model[i].ResponseText, "Not sure")No</label>
            <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model[i].ResponseText, "Agree")Agree </label>
          </div>
          @Html.HiddenFor(a => Model[i].QuestionId)
        }
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try and update here with my results. Thanks for checking.

Comment: That was it ! You saved me , Sir !